# Sending complexObj that has other complexObject[] inside it via POST from View

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have to send TestArr with filled `Name` from input form and also 0, 1 or a lot `ComplexObj`s with that `TestArr`

Unfortunely my implementation of nested form is not binding `ComplexObj[]` really well - it just does not work. Any idea how to do that? I tried with `BeginCollectionItemCore` but it didn't really work for me in that case

```
public class TestArr
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public ComplexObj[] complex { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public class ComplexObj
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string a { get; set; }
    public string b { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Name, complex")] TestArr input)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _context.Add(input);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    return View();
}
```

---

```
<form asp-action="Create">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div id="ComplexObj">
        <label class="control-label">a</label>
        <input asp-for="complex[0].a" class="form-control" />

        <label class="control-label">b</label>
        <input asp-for="complex[0].b" class="form-control" />       

        <label class="control-label">a</label>
        <input asp-for="complex[1].a" class="form-control" />

        <label class="control-label">b</label>
        <input asp-for="complex[1].b" class="form-control" />
    </div>

    <button type="button" id="addComplex" onclick="test()">addComplex</button>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</form>
```

## Edit

WTF? I changed `complex` to `Complex` in `TestArr`, `[Bind()]` and `View` and it started working

But when I generate input forms dynamically from javascript as `.innerHTML +=`, then it stops...

```
<script>
    var counter = 0;
    function test()
    {
        var div = document.getElementById('ComplexObj');
        div.appendChild +=
        `
            <label class="control-label">a</label>
            <input asp-for="Complex[${counter}].a" class="form-control" />

            <label class="control-label">b</label>
            <input asp-for="Complex[${counter}].b" class="form-control" />
        `;

        counter++;
    }
</script>
```

Which browser's renders as:

```
<label class="control-label">a</label>
<input asp-for="Complex[0].a" class="form-control">

<label class="control-label">b</label>
<input asp-for="Complex[0].b" class="form-control"></div>
```

So, the whole div looks like:

```
<div id="ComplexObj" style="height: 200px;">
    <label class="control-label">a</label>
    <input asp-for="Complex[0].a" class="form-control">

    <label class="control-label">b</label>
    <input asp-for="Complex[0].b" class="form-control">
</div>
```

But Controller sees it as a `null`.

Comment: What do you mean _nested form_ - you do not have nested forms. And what problem are you having - the code you have shown will bind fine.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Well maybe actually "nested" is not the best word. ``And what problem are you having - the code you have shown will bind fine`` for some reason in Controller.Create method my complex[] is null.

Comment: How are you generating the inputs dynamically. Are the indexers zero-based and consecutive? (I have already given you links in your previous question to show you how to do that.

Comment: @StephenMuecke F5 - I added the code

Comment: Read the link I gave you - the generate html needs to be `<input name="Complex[0].a" .... />` etc

Comment: @StephenMuecke Jesus, please write it as an answer, so I'll be able to accept it.

Comment: @StephenMuecke also - Thanks! ps: srsly write it as answer :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181189/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-ubuntucore).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

Change:

`<input asp-for="Complex[0].b" class="form-control">`

to:

`<input name="Complex[0].b" class="form-control">`